# PHP Array to String Conversion When Adding Strings in Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object which contains currency properties with their respective values. I need to add an extra amount to these, which I have simplified by appending a "+ TAX" value.

But I keep getting "array to string conversion" error on the first line within the foreach. I don't understand why - the values are strings. "

Worst still, the new object property duplicates within itself.

Here's my code

```
<?php

$result = new stdClass();
$result->GBP = "10.00";
$result->USD = "12.00";


foreach ($result as $currency => $value) {
   $currencyWithTax = $value .' + TAX';
   $result->total[$currency] = $currencyWithTax;
}

print_r($result);
```

I created an [3v4l here](https://3v4l.org/fVjeN) to demonstrate.

So I get the "array to string conversion" error, and my output looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GBP] => 10.00
    [USD] => 12.00
    [total] => Array
        (
            [GBP] => 10.00 + TAX
            [USD] => 12.00 + TAX
            [total] => Array + TAX
        )

)
```

I cannot figure out how to resolve the "Array to string" error, and ultimately why the "total" property is duplicated within the "total" property. I need my final output to look like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GBP] => 10.00
    [USD] => 12.00
    [total] => Array
        (
            [GBP] => 10.00 + TAX
            [USD] => 12.00 + TAX
        )

)
```

What have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: the object is live, as you loop over you add an array, then at some point $value will be an array https://3v4l.org/gFTCh plop (array) in front of $result to cast it to an array https://3v4l.org/nCSgT

Comment: In your foreach you are adding an array to your object, the 'total'.
At some point your code will do a 'total' + TAX , thus the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the object while you're looping over it, adding a `total` property. So a later iteration of the loop tries to use `total` as a currency and create another element in the nested `total` array.

Use a separate variable during the loop, then add it to the object afterward.

```
$totals = [];
foreach ($result as $currency => $value) {
   $currencyWithTax = $value .' + TAX';
   $totals[$currency] = $currencyWithTax;
}

$result->total = $totals;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach is adding USD as an array

Try this

```
<?php

$result = new stdClass();
$result->GBP = "10.00";
$result->USD = "12.00";

foreach ($result as $currency => $value) {
   if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) continue;
   $currencyWithTax = $value .' + TAX';
   $result->total[$currency] = $currencyWithTax;
}

print_r($result);
```